# How to create NSbutton inside an NSTextfield

Tags: nsview, nstextfield, nsbutton, nstextfieldcell, nsbuttoncell

In my application I need to show one label which showing the content and in the end of the label i need to show one button with close icon that will perform some action.

Can any one suggest way how to do this.